# Why can't I get Int types from my Firestore DocumentSnapshot?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I can get any type from my Firestore [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) except for `Int`:

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), Cloud Firestore's integral type values are 64 bit signed, which means you would need a JVM long to hold it without possibly losing data.  If you really must store an integral number as a JVM int type, you should just cast the value obtained from `getLong()` to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Using kotlin `Int` class will do

```
val user1MinAge = dataSnapshot.getValue(Int::class.java)
```